# Issue with SQLDatabase.from_uri in langchain when including views

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I am currently working with the SQLDatabase.from_uri method in langchain to include tables and views in my database. While I have successfully included tables and they are working as expected, I am encountering difficulties when attempting to add views to the database.

## This is not working for views ( working for tables in the same database)

```
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(database_uri, include_views=["view1"])
```

error is 'view1' not found

expected to run the SQLDatabaseChains

```
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm,db, prompt)
db_chain.run(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SQLDatabase.from_uri` method doesn't allow you to explicitly mention the list of views you wish to include, but one possibility is to set `view_support=True`:

```
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(
    database_uri,
    schema="schema name", #if required
    include_tables=['table1','table2'],
    view_support=True
)
```